# Validating Input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I'm working on a page that has a text box and a button (there's more to it, but these are the things that are giving me trouble). When the button is clicked, it's supposed to verify that there are only 3 letters entered in the text box.

Here is the html creating the input box and button:

```
<form>
    Enter 3 letters: <input type="text" id="3letters"> <br>
    <input type = "button" id = "check" value = "Send" onclick="validate()">
</form>
```

And here is the Javascript function to check the input:

```
function validate() {
    var TTinput = document.getElementById("3letters").value;

    if(TTinput < 3) {
        alert("Please enter 3 letters");
    }
}
```

To test that this works I'm trying to enter only a single letter, but when I click the button, nothing happens. Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `length` property:

```
if (TTinput.length < 3)
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, duh. I knew that, must've blanked for a minute ha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is to set to the `TTinput` variable the value of the text box. So now `TTinput` contains a `string`. What you need is to get its `length`, and the length of a string in javascript can be got by the `lenght` property:

```
var str = "ABCD";
str.length; // 4
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp

```
function validate() {
    var TTinput = document.getElementById("3letters").value;
    var input_length = TTinput.length;
    if(input_length < 3) {
        alert("Please enter 3 letters");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want exactly 3 characters use:

```
if(TTinput.length < 3 || TTinput.length > 3) {
    alert("Please enter 3 letters");
}
```

or

```
if(TTinput.length != 3) {
    alert("Please enter 3 letters");
}
```

*This (`TTinput.length < 3`) alone will consider 4, 7, 350,... characters valid.

Comment: I didnt say `true`, I said the script considers it valid because `< 3` evaluating `true` means the input was valid since the error message is inside the if block. (I changed it to show both `!=' and the '<3` `>3' (trying to show the OP that it can be a range if necessary).

Comment: Right, this is how I had it done at first, but since it wasn't working was going to test it with just using less than. Now that it works I'll be adding the || back in. Thanks!